# Multiindex Merge returns empty df but join should be valid

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I'm trying to join two dataframes which include, respectively, total olympic medals by country code and year and country population by country code and year. Each is a dataframe of one column with identical multiindex (country, population).

The dataframes may not necessarily include the same Countries and Years, for example Olympic years are not as many as general years, and some country codes are missing from the population estimate dataset. A couple of extracts to illustrate the datastructure, for ITA and a bunch of years that partially overlap:

med:

```
          Medals
Cty Year        
ITA 1960      88
    1964      50
    1968      32
    1972      25
    1976      31
```

pop:

```
          Population
Cty Year            
ITA 1960  50199700.0
    1961  50536350.0
    1962  50879450.0
    1963  51252000.0
    1964  51675350.0
```

When I use this command, I get an empty dataframe.

```
[In] df = pd.merge(med, pop, left_index=True, right_index=True)
[In] df
[Out] Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Medals, Population]
Index: []
```

I've also tried by using reset_index on each dataframe and then passing this:

```
[In] df = pd.merge(med, pop, on=['Cty','Year'])
[In] df
[Out] Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Cty, Year, Population, Medals]
Index: []
```

It seems to have created the dataframe with expected column names, but for some reason it's not managing to merge even the combination of Cty and Year indexes that exist in both (which would be my aim with this inner join).

Based on the two subsets of data I've posted earlier on, an expected output should look like this:

```
          Medals  Population
Cty Year        
ITA 1960      88  50199700.0
    1964      50  51675350.0
```

I've searched thoroughly this website and others and I can't wrap my head around it! Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: pd.concat is the way

Comment: you probably have different dtypes in your two indexes, e.g. year is a string in one and integer in the other

Comment: @root thank you, that was it. One index had years stored as int64 and the other as a string. I converted the strings to int64 and the merge operation worked! I should have thought about that.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the issue wasn't with my syntax for merge or concat, but rather the fact that in the Multiindex one dataframe had the Year stored as str, the other as int64.

I used the following code to make the str one into int64 and the merge operator worked as expected afterwards:

```
pop.index = pop.index.set_levels([pop.index.levels[0], pop.index.levels[1].astype(int)])
```

Only reason why I'm posting this as an answer to my own post is to evidence the comment where I thank root for the hint, in case other people have similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need an inner merge:

```
import pandas as pd

med = pd.DataFrame([['ITA', 1960, 88],    
                    ['ITA', 1964, 50],
                    ['ITA', 1968, 32],
                    ['ITA', 1972, 25],
                    ['ITA', 1976, 31]],
                   columns=['Cty', 'Year', 'Medals'])

pop = pd.DataFrame([['ITA', 1960, 50199700],    
                    ['ITA', 1961, 50536350],
                    ['ITA', 1962, 50879450],
                    ['ITA', 1963, 51252000],
                    ['ITA', 1964, 51675350]],
                   columns=['Cty', 'Year', 'Population'])

med = med.set_index(['Cty', 'Year'])
pop = pop.set_index(['Cty', 'Year'])

pd.merge(med, pop, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)

#           Medals  Population
# Cty Year                    
# ITA 1960      88    50199700
#     1964      50    51675350
```

Comment: Thank you jpp. As noted in the comments, the syntax I was using was correct, except the Year part of the MultiIndex was stored as a string for one, and as a int64 for the other dataframe. Converting to have both as int64 allowed the merge operation to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Data from jpp

```
pd.concat([pop,med],1).dropna()
Out[1496]: 
          Population  Medals
Cty Year                    
ITA 1960  50199700.0    88.0
    1964  51675350.0    50.0
```

Or just set `inner` inside `concat`

```
pd.concat([pop,med],axis=1, join='inner')
Out[1497]: 
          Population  Medals
Cty Year                    
ITA 1960    50199700      88
    1964    51675350      50
```

Comment: Thank you Wen. As noted in the comments, the syntax I was using was correct, except the Year part of the MultiIndex was stored as a string for one, and as a int64 for the other dataframe. Converting to have both as int64 allowed the merge operation to work correctly.